# Is it safe to join a table twice in the same query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to write some linq (linq-to-sql) for a search page that allows the user to search for cars and optionally include search criteria for the car's parts.  The two tables are `CAR` and `CAR_PARTS`.  Here is what I have so far:

```
var query = db.CAR;

//if the user provides a car name to search by, filter on car name (this works)
if(model.CarName != "")
{
   query = from c in query
           where c.Name == model.CarName
           select c;
}

//if the user provides a car part name to filter on, join the CAR_PART table
if(model.CarPartName != "")
{
   query = from c in query
           join parts in db.CAR_PARTS on c.ID equals parts.CarID
           where parts.PartName == model.CarPartName
           select c;
}

//if the user provides a car part code to filter on, join the CAR_PART table
if(model.CarPartCode != "")
{
   query = from c in query
           join parts in db.CAR_PARTS on c.ID equals parts.CarID
           where parts.PartCode == model.CarPartCode 
           select c;
}
```

If the user decides they want to search on both `CarPartName` and `CarPartCode`, this logic would result in the `CAR_PART` table being joined twice.  This feels wrong to me, but is this the correct way to handle this?

How would you write this?

Comment: Right now you're going to override the query anyways. If the user enters CartPartName and CarPartCode, only the query for CartPartCode will be used.

Comment: @JesseMoreland No.  It will apply all of the codes that are there, one after the other.

Comment: I stand corrected =).

Comment: Why not search if the CarName is not null first? and then search if CarPartName is not null AND CarPartCode is not null

Answer (score 1):

It's legal to do so, but whether it makes sense, depends on your datamodel and your desired outcome.

Generally your code does the following if `partname` and `partcode` are defined

1. Join the `cars` table with the `parts` table with `partname` as join condition
2. Join the result of the first join again with the `parts` table with `partcode` as join condition.

Thus, this is equal to a join with join condition `car.partname = part.name and car.partcode = part.code`. I don't know, whether this is your desired behaviour or not.

There are some cases to distinguish

**Joining with *AND* condition**

*CASE 1.1:  name and code of a part are keys in the parts table*

In this case for each `name`  and `code` are each unique in the parts table, thus for each `name`  there is exactly one `code`. The double join is not necessary, and may even lead to wrong results, because

1. if selected `name` and `code` identify the same part, it's the first join will already get the desired results
2. if `name` and `code` identifiy different parts, your result will be empty because the condition cannot be fullfilled.

In that situation I would suggest to write is as follows

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarPartName)){
    // your join on partname
} else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarPartCode)) {
    // your join on partcode
}
```

*CASE 1.2:  name and code of a part are NOT keys in the parts table*

In this case, neither `name` nor `code` may be unique, and for one `name` there may be different `code`s and vice versa. Here the double join is necessary and will only return results containing parts which match both, `name` and `code`

**Joining with *OR* condition**

If on the other hand you want your join condition to be like `car.partname = part.name and car.partcode = part.code` you have to consider the following cases

*CASE 2.1 name and code are keys*

Here applies the same as above in case 1.1

*CASE 2.2 name and code are NOT keys*

Here you can't use the stepwise approach, because the result of the first join will only contain cars, where the `name` matches. There may be parts where only the `code` condition matches, but they can never be included in the final result, if they are not contained in the result of the first match. So in this case, you will have to define your query something like this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarPartName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarPartCode)) {
    query = from c in query
        join parts in db.CAR_PARTS on c.ID equals parts.CarID
        where parts.PartName == model.CarPartName || parts.PartCode == model.CarPartCode
        select c;
} else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarPartName)) {
    query = from c in query
        join parts in db.CAR_PARTS on c.ID equals parts.CarID
        where parts.PartName == model.CarPartName
        select c;    
} else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarPartCode)) {
    query = from c in query
        join parts in db.CAR_PARTS on c.ID equals parts.CarID
        where parts.PartCode == model.CarPartCode
        select c;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong in there is actually with proper relations you don't need the join at all. Add that the behavior of LinqToSQL you can write that as:

```
var query = db.CAR
       .Where( c => 
          ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarName) 
          || c.Name == model.CarName ) &&
          ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarPartName) 
          || c.Parts.Any( p => p.PartName == model.CarPartName )) &&
          ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CarPartCode)
          || c.Parts.Any( p => p.PartCode == model.CarPartCode )));
```

Yours would work provided query is IQueryable (db.CAR.AsQueryable()). The two Linq approaches are similar but not the same. Depending on your real necessity yours might be the correct one or the wrong one. Yours would produce two inner joins, while this one simply create 2 exists check. Assume you have:

```
Car, Id:5, Name: Volvo
```

And parts like:

```
CarID:5, PartName:HeadLights, PartCode:1 ... other details
CarID:5, PartName:HeadLights, PartCode:2 ... other details
CarID:5, PartName:HeadLights, PartCode:3 ... other details
```

If user asks with model.CarName = "Volvo" and model.PartName = "HeadLights", you would get back the same Volvo 3 times. In second approach, you get back a single Volvo.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

I feel more comfortable with fluent syntax, but I'm sure something similar to the following will work for you. I would check the fields in your model as part of a Select statement and then conditionally join using one field or the other. If neither are set, leave it null.

```
var query = db.CAR;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(model.CarName))
{
    query = query.Where(car => car.Name == model.CarName);
}

var items = query.Select(car => new
{
     Car = car, // maybe better to split this up into different fields, but I don't know what the car object looks like

     // I assume your Car entity model has a navigation property to parts:
     CarPart = !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(model.CarPartName) 
               ? car.Parts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.PartName == model.CarPartName)
               : !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(model.CarPartCode)
               ? car.Parts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.PartCode == model.CarPartCode)
               : null
})
.ToList();
```

This does mean that the Code will be ignored if the Name is filled in. Reverse it if it needs to be the other way around. Or if you want to use both fields, you can put the string null checks in the Where clause.